# PDF: Two date fields: One selected by user; other identical, but + 2 years

Tags: javascript, date, pdf, adobe

I haven't seen this particular question, so hope I'm not reasking!

I have two date fields in a PDF: Warranty Start and Warranty End. Ideally, I would like to have the user select the date in the Warranty Start, and then the Warranty End be auto-filled with that same date plus 2 years.

i.e. User selects Warranty Start date of 9/14/17, so Warranty End Date auto-fills with 9/14/19.

I know that JavaScript can be used within PDFs, but I'm not familiar enough with the structure to do much of use!

Comment: How to add time intervals to dates is well covered in other questions, just search on "how to add <unit>". If you're asking how to do it in a PDF, best you supply some code and show where things are going wrong. See [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)